# Kubernetes Pod with hostNetwork True cannot reach external IPs of services in the same cluster

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minio

### Problem

I have two pods `A` and `B` running in a cluster on minikube, both have external IPs `www.service-a.com` and `www.service-b.com`. Both external IPs are accessible from outside.

I need `A` to be able to call `B` with it's external IP rather than its cluster DNS, that is `A` needs to use `www.service-b.com` rather than `b.svc.cluster.local` (which does work but I can't use it).

I set `A` to use `hostNetwork: true` and `dnsPolicy: ClusterFirstWithHostNet`. If I spin up a NodeJS docker container manually, it indeed can connect and find it. However, `A` is still unable to connect to `service-b.com`. Am I using `hostNetwork` wrong? How can I configure my pod to connect to `b` in that way?

A's Deployment YAML

```
...
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: a-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: a-app
    spec:
      hostNetwork: true
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirstWithHostNet
      containers:
...
```

B's service YAML

```
...
spec:
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: ...
    targetPort: ...
    protocol: TCP
    name: http
...
```

### Background:

I'm using Minio (a local S3-like solution) and I need to presign the URLs to get and put objects. Minio's pods are running in the same cluster as my authentication pod which would generate the presigned urls. The presigned urls would be used from outside the cluster. Hence I can't sign the url with the cluster dns names like `minio.svc.cluster.local` because this URL would not be accessible from outside the cluster and replacing the host with `my-minio.com` and keeping the signature does not work because I guess minio signs the entire host and path. Hence I need to have my authentication pod connect to Minio's public facing `my-minio.com` instead which does not seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Grigoriy suggested, I used an ingress with `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/upstream-vhost`  annotation to forward all requests into the cluster with `Host: service-b` to resolve my issue. Previously I had `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1` which stripped the path from the request that caused a serious of issues, so I removed that. The details of how I got it working are here:

[NGINX controller Kubernetes: need to change Host header within ingress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64815229/nginx-controller-kubernetes-need-to-change-host-header-within-ingress)

Answer (score 6):

Regarding `hostNetwork`, it looks like you misunderstood it. Setting it to true means that Pod will have access to the host where it's running. In case of minikube it's VM and not your host where actual containers are running.

Also, i'm not sure how you expose your services to external world, but i suggest you to try [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) for that.

Comment: I've been just using a LoadBalancer with externalTrafficPolicy turned on. With an ingress would the pod be able to connect to the other pod via the ingress? I'm pretty novice at Kube.

Comment: Okay going to try that now. Will update here once I'm done

Comment: I deployed an ingress and a nginx controller

`NAMESPACE   NAME                HOSTS       ADDRESS     PORTS   AGE
my-namespace       my-minio   localhost   localhost   80      16m`

on my local machine, hitting localhost now directs to pod B but A is unable to hit `localhost` and get to pod B.

Comment: A method to replace the Host header with `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/upstream-vhost` seem pretty promising but, just putting that annotation there in my ingress doesn't seem to work out of the box. Perhaps it's because I installed nginx through helm?

Comment: @MathisHard Can you place another question, describing your issues with ingress/ingress controller? Seems to me like this is issue for another SO question.

Comment: @MathisHard For minikube you could just run `kubectl get pods -n kube-system` to install ingress controller. Here is [tutorial on how to set and use ingress in minikube](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/)

Comment: @MathisHard Also, can you update your question and add manifest for Ingress?

Comment: I have posted another question that involves the ingress solution to this particular problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64815229/nginx-controller-kubernetes-need-to-change-host-header-within-ingress

Comment: Actually got it to work turns out I shouldn't declare  rewrite-target and ssl-redirect. Replacing upstream-vhost works as expected. Now my problem is solved :)